# Why correct regexp not work in query-replace-regexp?

Tags: regular-expressions

I want to add 400 in every line where has text "**finished**".

Here text and regexp:

[image]

as you can see the regexp is correct

```
"finished":\s-*[0-9]+
```

Nice.

Now I use this regexp in `query-replace-regexp`

replace by

```
\1\,(+ 400 (string-to-number \2))
```

[image]

But the result is error:

```
replace-eval-replacement: Error evaluating replacement expression: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
```

Comment: In order to use '\1` and '\2' you need to define 2 [capture groups in your regexp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html).

Comment: @Juancho Thanks. This work:   M-C-% \("finished":[\s-]*\)\([0-9]+\) RET replace by -> 
     \1\,(1+ (string-to-number \2))RET